# Exclude NuGet dependency when creating NETStandard 2.0 NuGet Package

Tags: .net, msbuild, nuget, .net-standard-2.0

I am attempting to create a NuGet package on my .NET Standard 2.0 assembly. I added three (3) different NuGet packages using the PackageReference format, and I selected the "Generate NuGet package on build" option. Everything works fine, except that one of the packages I consumed only contains a .targets file, which I don't want to include as a dependency.

Is there any way to specify for a `PackageReference` to not be part of a package dependency when using msbuild on a .NET Standard assembly which has `GeneratePackageOnBuild` set to true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `PackageReference` item supports a few additional metadata values. one of them is `PrivateAssets` which controls which assets are NOT forwarded to consumers. When it is set to "all", the dependency entry in the generated nuspec is avoided entirely - i.e. the package won't show up in the dependency graph:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="JetBrains.Annotations" Version="11.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Strange, when I set that property earlier and compiled using msbuild through developer command prompt, it still listed the dependency. I added another package afterwards, and removed that package, and now msbuild honors the `PrivateAssets="All"` value. I'm not sure why adding/removing a different package fixed it, but now it works.

Comment: @m-y yeah seems a bit buggy... this worked for me by manually deleting the bin/obj folders and rebuilding.